# intern_profile_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong? I'm trying to create a simple multi users app in django and I can't quite tell what I'm missing in my view.

Here's what I have so far.

views.py

```
@method_decorator([login_required, intern_required], name='dispatch')
def intern_profile_view(request):
    
  if request.method == 'POST':
        
    user_form = InternSignUpForm(request.POST, prefix='UF')
    profile_form = InternProfileForm(request.POST, prefix='PF')
        
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        
        user.save()

        user.intern_profile.bio = profile_form.cleaned_data.get('bio')
        user.intern_profile.location = profile_form.cleaned_data.get('location')
        user.intern_profile.save()
            
    else:
        user_form = InternSignUpForm(prefix='UF')
        profile_form = InternProfileForm(prefix='PF')
        
    return render(request, 'interns/intern_profile.html',{
            'user_form': user_form,
            'profile_form': profile_form,
        })
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_intern = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class InternProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, 
           related_name='intern_profile')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikha\issue_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: intern_profile_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

urls.py

```
path('interns/', include(([
        path('', interns.intern_profile_view, name='intern_profile'),
    ], 'classroom'), namespace='interns')),
```

Comment: whats `intern_required`? - that decorator might be missing an argument. *spit balling*

Comment: `method_decorator` is supposed to be used along with the class views. So, I suspect, that the case